# Pintar un boton en b-table vue2.js +bootstrap4, bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table, bootstrap-vue

soy nuevo en esto con el trabajo en VUEJS y estoy haciendo un proyecto frontend en el que estoy listando los datos que tengo en el backend. Hasta la parte de visualización de datos va todo bien, pero ahora quiero agregarle 2 botones a cada fila de la tabla, de manera que se pueda editar o eliminar dichos datos. En mi archivo ListadeLibros.vue hasta ahora tengo esto:

```js
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  export default {
      data() {
          return {
              fields: [
                  { key: 'title', label: 'Título' },
                  { key: 'description', label: 'Descripción' },
                  { key: 'action', label: '' }
              ],
              books: []
          }
      },
      methods:{
          getBooks() {
              const path ='http://localhost:8000/book/'
              axios.get(path).then((response) => {
                  this.books = response.data
              })
                  .catch((error) => {
                      console.log(error)
                  })
          }
      },
      created(){
          this.getBooks()
      }
  }
  </script>
```

```css
<style lang="css" scoped>

  </style>
```

```html
 <template lang="html">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-left">
          <h2>Listado de Libros</h2>

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <b-table striped hover :items="books" :fields="fields">

             <template slot="action" slot-scope="data">
                <b-button size="sm" variant="primary">
                  Editar
                </b-button>
                <b-button size="sm" variant="danger">
                  Eliminar
                </b-button>

             </template>

            </b-table>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </template>
```

Donde en teoría y según todas las biblios deberían salir los 2 botones, alguna idea??
Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reemplaze

```
slot="action"
```

por

```
slot="cell(action)"

<template slot="cell(action)" slot-scope="data">
    ...
</template>
```

vea https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4480